# Is it possible to update a mysql table only if all matching rows will get updated?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, updates, transactional

I have a table that looks like this

```
| id | location | status | parent_id |   
-----------------------------------  
| 1  |  35      |   0    |   100     |  
| 2  |  35      |   1    |   100     |  
| 3  |  36      |   0    |   200     |  
| 4  |  36      |   0    |   200     |
```

I want to be able to update the group and set status = 0 of rows that match a certain parent_id if and only if all of the rows with the particular parent_id have status set to 0.

The use case is something like this:
An activity (parent_id) may be done at one of multiple locations. Each activity has some sub-activities. An activity may move from one location to another only if none of the sub-activities has started.

Would it be possible to do it transactionally in MySQL? If it is possible to do it without locking the whole table it would be much more efficient, but I am not sure if there is a single statement solution to that.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I missed out one important bit - the parent_id is the id to the table where the main activity is stored. Hence, a join of this table with itself on (id, parent_id) would be incorrect.

Comment: If all the rows with that parent have a status of 0, then the row in question already has a status of 0.  Hence, there is no need for the update.

Comment: Can sub-activities also have sub-activities?

Comment: @gordonlinoff I was stuck on how to figure out if all rows with that parent have the same status and then (and only then) change the group of those subactivities (and leave the status as 0)

Comment: @christhornhill In this case I can assume that sub-activities will not have sub-activities - i think using parent_id was possibly the source of confusion - parent_id is the id column of another table

Answer (score 2):

How about this. I haven't tested and the performance may not be the best.

```
UPDATE t 
JOIN (SELECT parent_id, max(status) AS ma, min(status) AS mi FROM t2 GROUP BY parent_id HAVING ma<=0 AND mi>=-1) AS children 
  ON t.id=children.parent_id 
SET status = 0;
```

EDIT
Changed to use max an min instead of sum to support the fact that status can be less than 0 and now also allowing -1 in the children to be updated.

Comment: I guess, it can be optimized by using `HAVING s = 0`  inside the subquery. In this case there is no need for `WHERE children.s = 0`

Comment: @stenix  My bad - my question was missing one crucial bit - I realized just now. The parent_id is actually the id of another table - activities (i.e parents) are in a different table and sub-activities(this table) is in another table. I have updated the question.

Comment: No problem, just join with that table then. I called it t2 or maybe it was the otherone that should be called t2, anyway you get the picture.

Comment: This is a legacy system where I just found that there status can be -1and if a parent has all children who are either -1 or 0 we are allowed to change groups. Here's a slightly ugly looking query I came up with which seems to be working (much testing needs to be done):  `update foo
 JOIN (select parent_id, count(*) as status_count from foo where parent_id = 200 and status in (0, -1) having status_count = (select count(*) as total_count from foo where parent_id = 200)) as x on x.parent_id = foo.parent_id
 SET status = 0, group_id = 98;`

Comment: I updated my reply to support also -1. You may have to run some analysis to determine which of queries performs best.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it seems to be working:

```
UPDATE foo
    JOIN 
        (SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS status_count FROM foo WHERE parent_id =   200 AND status IN (0, -1) 
         HAVING status_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM foo WHERE parent_id = 200)) 
    AS x ON x.parent_id = foo.parent_id
SET status = 0, group_id = 98;
```